# Не получается получить позицию элемента в методе onSwipe

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

хочу с помощью свайпа удалить элемент Recycler View. Но проблема в получении id элемента который свайпаю. Mетод `viewHolder.getItemId();` Возвращает -1. Вне зависимости от того какой элемент RecyclerView свайпать. Вот код:
AdminPage.java:

```java
public class AdminPage extends Activity {

    private static AdapterAdminPage adapterAdminPage;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> id;
    private static ArrayList<String> name;
    private static ArrayList<String> phone;
    private static ArrayList<String> address;
    private static ArrayList<String> pizzas;
    private TextView t;
    WorkBD workBD;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private static boolean b;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_page);
        workBD = new WorkBD(this);
    }

    public void Refresh(View v){
        getItemForAdapter();
    }

    private void getItemForAdapter(){
        id = new ArrayList<>();
        name = new ArrayList<>();
        address = new ArrayList<>();
        phone = new ArrayList<>();
        pizzas = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = workBD.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(WorkBD.TABLE_CONTACTS, null,null,null,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            try {
                id.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(WorkBD.KEY_ID)));
                String pizza1 = "Пепперони: " + Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("pizza1"))) + "\n";
                String pizza2 = "Кальцоне: " + Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("pizza2"))) + "\n";
                String pizza3 = "Четыре сезона: " + Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("pizza3"))) + "\n";
                String pizza4 = "Четыре сыра: " + Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("pizza4"))) + "\n";
                String pizza5 = "Мексиканская: " + Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("pizza5"))) + "\n";
                name.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WorkBD.KEY_NAME)));
                phone.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WorkBD.KEY_NUMBER)));
                address.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WorkBD.KEY_ADDRESS)));
                pizzas.add(pizza1 + pizza2 + pizza3 + pizza4 + pizza5);
            }

            catch (Exception e){
                t = findViewById(R.id.NoOrders);
                t.setText("ПОКА \n НЕТ \n ЗАКАЗОВ \n :/ \n \n \n");
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
        db.close();
        if(b){
            adapterAdminPage.refreshData(name,phone,address,pizzas);
            b = false;
        }
        else
        setAdapterAdminPage();
    }

    private void setAdapterAdminPage(){
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.AdminRecyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapterAdminPage = new AdapterAdminPage(name,phone,address,pizzas);
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemTouchHelper);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterAdminPage);
    }


    private final ItemTouchHelper.Callback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

        @Override
        public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            return makeMovementFlags(ItemTouchHelper.END, ItemTouchHelper.END);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int id = (int)viewHolder.getItemId();
            Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(id));
            SQLiteDatabase db = workBD.getReadableDatabase();
            //db.execSQL("DELETE FROM pizzaOrders WHERE ID IN (" + id + ")");
            b = true;
            getItemForAdapter();
            Log.i(TAG, "onSwiped");
        }

    };
}
```

Код адаптера

```java
public class AdapterAdminPage extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAdminPage.AdminHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> name;
    private ArrayList<String> address;
    private ArrayList<String> pizza;
    private ArrayList<String> phone;

    public AdapterAdminPage(ArrayList<String> Aname, ArrayList<String> Aphone, ArrayList<String> Aaddress, ArrayList<String> Apizza){
        name = Aname;
        address = Aaddress;
        pizza = Apizza;
        phone = Aphone;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdminHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    Context context = parent.getContext();

    int layoutIdForListIttem = R.layout.adapter_admin_panel;

    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View view = inflator.inflate(layoutIdForListIttem, parent, false);

    AdapterAdminPage.AdminHolder viewHolder = new AdapterAdminPage.AdminHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
    }

    public static class AdminHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView nameT;
        TextView phoneT;
        TextView commentT;
        TextView pizzaT;
        TextView adressT;

        public AdminHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameT = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Aname);
            phoneT = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Aphone);
            adressT = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Aadress);
            pizzaT = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Apizza);
        }

    }

    public void refreshData(ArrayList namik, ArrayList phonik, ArrayList addressik, ArrayList pizzik){

        name.clear();
        phone.clear();
        address.clear();
        pizza.clear();

        name = namik;
        phone = phonik;
        address = addressik;
        pizza = pizzik;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdminHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nameT.setText(name.get(position));
        holder.phoneT.setText(phone.get(position));
        holder.adressT.setText(address.get(position));
        holder.pizzaT.setText(pizza.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return name.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все понял в чём ошибка, нужно использовать .getAdapterPosition а не .getItemId().